# How to use the fabric.js library with the online library url?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to insert the Fabric.js library to test some things with:

```
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/fabric@latest/dist/fabric.js'></script>
```

But apparently dosen't work...

I'm just trying to do a basic free canvas like:

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  isDrawingMode: true
});

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  width: 60,
  height: 70,
  fill: 'red',
});
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.renderAll();
```

But still nothing appears on my project, i can't do or paint anything..

Anyone with some answers?

Comment: do you have any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need canvas element the html in order for fabricjs to work.
There are two ways to fix achieve this

1. Option 1. - Add canvas element in html.
   `<canvas id="c"/>`

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  isDrawingMode: true
});

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  width: 60,
  height: 70,
  fill: 'red',
});
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
  border-style: groove;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" />

<script src='https://unpkg.com/fabric@latest/dist/fabric.js'></script>
```

2. Option 2. - Add canvas element in html using javascript.

   ```
    var mycanvas = document.createElement("canvas"); 

    mycanvas.id = "mycanvas";  

    document.body.appendChild(mycanvas);
   ```

```js
var mycanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
mycanvas.id = "c";
document.body.appendChild(mycanvas);
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  isDrawingMode: true
});

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  width: 60,
  height: 70,
  fill: 'red',
});
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
  border-style: groove;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://unpkg.com/fabric@latest/dist/fabric.js'></script>
```

Comment: Finally i solved it by adding the src library script code on the body:

    <script src='https://unpkg.com/fabric@latest/dist/fabric.js'></script>

Thank you for your answer, it helped too!